# Calibration pattern chessboard

Tags: ros, calibration, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users:

I am doing a calibration camera and I have to have a calibration pattern in Gazebo.
I like to know if there is a .stl calibration pattern chessboard file on the internet to do that.
And if there is not, how can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219380/calibration-pattern-chessboard/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-10-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-20**:
Is this a duplicate of [textures in a stl file](http://answers.ros.org/question/219467/textures-in-a-stl-file/)?

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-10-22**:
both are fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can render a checker/chessboard texture in gimp, export it as a png.

[image: image description]

Or search for an existing one https://www.google.com/search?q=checkerboard+opencv&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Then create a plate model in Blender and apply the saved texture to a face using a tutorial like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POWq9aeDLls

[image: image description]

Export the textured cube model as an obj, load it into meshlab, then export it as a dae (dae works better than stl in Gazebo).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-10-22**:
Thanks a lor. Problem fixed.